# Multipicker activity not start in android

Tags: android

I have create the multi picker image function from gallery.its working fine only Sometimes the Multi-picker Intent activity not starts, it shows "No Activity found to handle Intent" error any one help me to solve this error. But sometimes its working fine.`

```
btnGalleryPickMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(i, 200);
            }
        });

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

        ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();


        for (String string : all_path) {
            CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();
            item.sdcardPath = string;

            dataT.add(item);
            //
            String size=item.sdcardPath;
            Log.d("size--", size);
            image1.add(item.sdcardPath);
            Log.d("map--", String.valueOf(image1));


            ArrayList<String> ImgData =image1;
            Log.d("ImgData--", String.valueOf(ImgData));


            for (int i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {
                map.add(ImgData.get(i).toString());


            }

        }

        viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
        adapter.addAll(dataT);

        new ImageUploadTask()
                .execute(count + "", "pk" + count + ".jpg");
    }
}
```

Logcat error`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.airstar.abservetech.airstar, PID: 5646
                                                                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=luminous.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK }
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1663)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3513)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3474)
                                                                                   at com.airstar.abservetech.airstar.Add_room$5.onClick(Add_room.java:296)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

create the Intent and check if it is available or not using below function

```
public static boolean isAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
   final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> list =
      mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
         PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   return list.size() > 0;
}
```

**Update Your Code:**

```
btnGalleryPickMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
                if(isAvailable(mContext,i))
                startActivityForResult(i, 200);
            }
        });
```